# How to have a fixed marign to the end of page in various screen?

Tags: css

Here is my [code](https://github.com/kenpeter/margin_content).

Here is what is looking currently.

[image]

We know that the content height of grey area is varied. How can I have a 30px fixed margin (for the grey div) to the end of page, in mobile and bigger screen?

Comment: `30px` is already fixed so what is the issue exactly?

Comment: @TemaniAfif, if you look at the screenshort, the grey div to the end of page is greater than 30px. Is it way to have constant margin when I resize the browser? e.g. the grey area needs to automatically extend itself.

Comment: so you want height:100% - 30px then ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif correct.

Answer (score 0):

Make your element full height and use `calc()` to remove the *fixed margin*:

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  background:pink;
}
.box {
  height:calc(100vh - 30px - 5px);
  margin:5px;
  background:grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have used bootstrap it takes container properties of bootstrap. To over ride this change the name of the container class to custom container in your style Css page. 
Then apply it in the doc as stated below.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially add `min-height: calc(100vh - 60px);` to the `.container`.  This will make the container have a minimum height that's 100% of the viewport's height minus 60px. The 60px comes from the margins you have applied to the top and bottom of this div. I hope this helps :)